# c# create class instance using method inside class

Tags: c#, class, methods, instance

I have a class called User, where one can initialize it like so:

```
User user = new User();
```

This works great, but in some cases I want to call a static method *inside* the User class, so that the code now looks like this:

```
User user = User.SomeMethod();
```

I am sure that it is not extremely difficult, because I have seen it done in `System.Diagnostics.Process`:

```
Process p = Process.Start("filename");
```

How can I make my class do the same?

EDIT:

This is what my class looks like:

```
public class User
    {
        public User()
        {
            // this runs when User u = new User() is called
        }

        public static void SomeMethod()
        {
            // I want this to run when "User u = User.SomeMethod() is called
        }
    }
```

Am I missing a method constructor?

Comment: You can add a static method to the User Class

Comment: What don't you understand? Are you asking how to create a static method? How to return a value?

Comment: `public static User Create() => new User();`

Comment: You need to make your method return a value.

Answer (score 3):

Are you talking about something like this?
There's no method constructor, but you can call the constructor from inside a method. You could also have a private constructor that is called from that method.

```
class User {
    ...

   public User() {}
   private User(string s) {
       // Can only be called inside User class
       Console.WriteLine(s);
   }

    public static User Create() {
        return new User("Creating user from method...");
    }
}
```

Comment: I originally intend to make SomeMethod() void, because I don't want to return anything

Comment: how would somemethod() return type be void if you want to initialize a variable via it...

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is called a Factory pattern. Most of the cases you create a separate class, add Factory name into it and it will create User class for you. Use factory pattern if you want to control how the User class is created:

```
public class UserFactory
    {
        public static User CreateUser()
        {
            return new User();
        }
    }
```

> Note: Above code is just simple explanation, there are more things about factory pattern and it is more complex than a few lines of code. If you need to learn more you can check the next [link](https://www.dotnetperls.com/factory)  that will give you a detailed explanation.

If you want the User class to be responsible for creating itself via static method then look at the example below:

```
public class User
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public User()
        {

        }
        public static User CreateUser()
        {
            return new User();
        }
        public static User CreateUser(string name, string lastName)
        {
            return new User
            {
                Name = name,
                LastName = lastName
            };
        }
    }
```